# Exporting EfficientDet D0 model as tflite model

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, object-detection, tensorflow-lite

I have trained my efficientdet d0 model using tensorflow object detection API but couldn't convert the saved_model into tflite model to deploy it in an edge devices like jetson nano or xavier.

How can I convert this particular model into tflite version?(Even so many blogs have used SSD model for deployment purposes.)

Comment: please, post [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Did you able to convert to tflite ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to deployment on edge devices go through this free course on tensorflow-lite

https://www.udacity.com/course/intro-to-tensorflow-lite--ud190

This will give you a intro on deployment on edge devices